# Move to another URL selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to move to another URL without creating new istance of IwebDriver?
All I want is to stay on the same browser just close the current page and open the new one.

I have tried just to navigate driver to another page second time but it didn't work. Something like this:

```
Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.outlook.com/");
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your code works for me. It loads in the same browser. But I'm using the same instance of DRIVER to accomplish that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works:

```
driver.Url = "http://www.outlook.com";
driver.Navigate();
```

I have no idea why, but `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(...)` does not work sometimes. In addition, you should have a `IWebDriver` instance anyway, and use it to navigate to sites (you only need one).

Comment: I would like to know what is the reason for this working when is the same thing as Driver.Navigate().ToURL(); just in 2 steps.

Comment: @Mystia when you find out, let me know. This is just something that I've found to work over the past few years so I figured I'd save people the time by answering with it. It sounds like a bug in drivers. The vast majority of my work isn't selenium - I just play with it :)

Comment: Will let you know as soon as I find out , thank you for help anyway!